# How to pass a parameter to SQL Query after conditional split in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am fairly new at working with SSIS, and everything was straight forward until I came across this. I have a system that has data everywhere and I am trying to clean everything up by normalizing it.

Now my issue is, in my SSIS I have a conditional split, what I would like to do is to take that value which I just split it up and pass it as a parameter to a query I already have.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Question is broad and unclear.   "Passing a parameter to a query I have" isn't something you do in SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You know the thing is the value of `Parameter` in SSIS cannot be updated during the run-time. Since you are talking about the `conditional split` transformation, even if you are trying to use `Variable` instead, its value can only be updated when your current `data flow task` is done. So I think you should better adjust your logic a little bit.